# Can't click the button to view more results, getting exception element not clickable

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

I am trying to scrape some data from this site https://easy.co.il/list/Shopping, when you scroll down the list of businesses it has a button at the end to view more results, when I try to click it using .click function it raises an exception that element is not intractable, I have also tried using Keys.ENTER still same exception, I have tried waiting for the element to be clickable using this code.

```
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="biz-item "]')
print(len(results))

button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@id="nextPageButton"]')))
```

the len(results) prints 25 which is all the businesses visible till the view more results button.

I have also tried locating the button, the element is visible on the page but just not clickable.

Can someone please look in to this? Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `scroll` the element before click.Use `location_once_scrolled_into_view` to scroll the element.

```
driver.get("https://easy.co.il/list/Shopping")
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@id="nextPageButton"]')))
button.location_once_scrolled_into_view
button.click()
```

---

If you still gets the error then induce java scripts executor to click.

```
driver.get("https://easy.co.il/list/Shopping")
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@id="nextPageButton"]')))
button.location_once_scrolled_into_view
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

Comment: The WebDriverWait command doesn't get executed properly, it throws timeout exception, if it returns a clickable button then the whole problem is solved, the button is not getting clickable even if I give 30 wait time instead of 10, it is still giving me timeout exception

Answer (score 0):

Use `.visibility_of_element_located` method, then scroll:

```
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@id="nextPageButton"]')))
button.location_once_scrolled_into_view
button.click()
```

Comment: the problem is that i get timeout exception on WebDriverWait, I dont get past that point so I can call .click() method on it

Comment: @ShahzaibZubair see the updated answer. Use `.visibility_of_element_located` first.

Comment: .visibility_of_element_located still gives timeout exception but I tried locating the element with the help of simple find_element_by_xpath and then used .location_once_scrolled_into_view and then .click and it did the trick, thank you for leading me there (Y)